# Запуск python скрипта по нажатию кнопки на веб-странице

Tags: python, django

Простая задача.

- Есть скрипт на python, который делает записи в БД.
- Есть сервер на Django, который выводит данные из БД в виде таблицы.

**Проблема:** хочу, но не могу придумать, как сделать кнопку на странице с табличкой, которая запускала бы `python` скрипт.

Вот, казалось бы, [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166941/create-html-button-to-run-python-script)

Вот, я его пытаюсь повторить:

**html**

```
<form action= '{% url "my_view_name"%}' method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="submit"  value="Обновить" id="toggle1" />
</form>
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', views.my_view ,name='my_view_name'),
```

**views.py**

```
from .main import Parser
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p = Parser(start_page=1, end_page=10)
        print("my view doing something")
        p.parse_all_pages()
    #Do your stuff ,calling whatever you want from set_gpio.py
    context = RequestContext(request, {'quote_list': Quote.objects.order_by('-id')[:10],})
    return render(request, 'index/index.html', context)
```

Вот, у меня ничего не получается:

> POST /index/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0

Я что-то упускаю в происходящем и до конца не понимаю, как оно вообще в теории должно работать.

Если есть возможность, дайте ссылку на туториал или объясните вкратце, как оно должно быть, и что у меня не так.
Есть ли возможно сделать такой же функционал (запуск скрипта на питоне по нажатию кнопки на странице) через `ajax` или `php`?

Comment: Можете уточнить правильно ли у вас настроенны адреса в urls.py, так как в вашем примере вы обращаетесь к /index/ `POST /index/ ...`, но в urls.py у вас сначится адрес корня `'^$'`, или вы включаете адреса этого под-проэкта где-то выше?

Comment: Наверное если нужно событие при нажатии, то тут js, а если хочешь чтобы выполнялся python скрипт, используй ajax для вызова скрипта.